# 422 (Unprocessable Content) when trying to log in

Tags: php, laravel

**login.blade.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <title>로그인 페이지</title>

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>              
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#loginform').submit(function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault(); 
                    
                    var formData = $(this).serialize(); 
                    
                    $.ajax({
                        url: '/login', 
                        method: 'POST',
                        data: formData,
                        success: function(response) {
                            if(response.success == true){
                                window.location.href = "/";            
                            }
                            console.log(response);
                        },
                        error: function(xhr) {
                            var errors = xhr.responseJSON;
                            console.log(errors);
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>    
        <div class="container">
            <form id="loginform" action="/login" method="post">
                {{ csrf_field() }}
                <dl>
                    <dt>이메일</dt><dd><input type="email" name="email" size="30" value="{{ old('email') }}" require></dd>
                    <dt>비밀번호</dt><dd><input type="password" name="password" size="30" require></dd>
                </dl>

                @isset($errors)
                    <p style="color:red">{{ $errors->first('message') }}</p>
                @endisset  

                <button type="submit">로그인</button>

                <div>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="remember" name="remember">
                    <label for="remember">이메일 기억하기</label>
                </div>

            </form>
            <a href="/register">관리자 등록하기</a>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**StorePostRequest.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class StorePostRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     */
    public function authorize(): bool
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array<string, \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\ValidationRule|array|string>
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|email|unique:admin,email',
            'password' => 'required|string|min:8|confirmed',
        ];
    }
}
```

In the login page, the data was sent to the server through ajax through the name value in the email and password form. However, as a result of the response, a POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/login 422 (Unprocessable Content) error occurred in Chrome, and to solve this, I checked whether the field values ​​matched.

The value returned by the response in the Chrome Developer Tools
"message": "The email has already been taken. (and 1 more error)",
"errors": {
"email": [
"The email has already been taken."
],
"password": [
"The password field confirmation does not match."
]
}

I'm not sure where the code went wrong. Please help me how to solve it.

Comment: validation failed because the `email` address being submitted already exists in the database ... this validation looks like the validation you would use for creation/registration, not to login a user

Answer (score 2):

You do not have an input `name` or `email` or `password` or `password_confirmation`

In your rules have `confirmed`:
`'password' => '.....|confirmed',`

You need push a field `password_confirmation`  . [Document](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/validation#rule-confirmed)

Check your config auth model is admin or not?

Check your email from form request and data of field email of table `admin`

Comment: I don't know how to write code
Can you give me a code example?

Comment: You can search with google with `example code login with laravel` :)))

Comment: Or you can ask ChatGPT with `i want an example of login process with laravel, from frontend to backend with validation`

Comment: "message": "The email has already been taken." I am getting an error, can you tell me the cause?

Comment: Try with a different email id, the old one may already saved to the table that's why it shows validation message.

Comment: password (and password_confirmation)  should to alphanumeric and greater than or equal to 8 characters. <input id="password_confirmation" name="password_confirmation" type="password" v-model="form.password_confirmation" />